# Best way to share Eclipse WorkSpace

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

What is the best way to share my Eclipse Workspace between my Computer and Laptop (Windows 7 & Windows 8). I am familiar with SVN but after a while my SVN crashes and I cannot commit because all my files are outdated (they are not).

How do you share your Workspace between several computer?

Comment: Best way to share/manage source code is no doubt to use SCM like SVN or Git. To share/manage workspace, try set them up in cloud drive like Google Drive or Dropbox, though personally I don't put the source directly in the workspace myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner solution could be to create a workspace in each computer and then just to use a SCM.
I use a workspace for each of my 3 computers (My laptop at work - fedora 17, my personal laptop - MacOSX and my desktop - Win7 ) they have their own workspace but i share-update my projects through github.

**Update:**

But to reach your aim, you could also upload to your SCM your workspace settings:

I found this useful information [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w).

> So the short answer is: If you want to create a new eclipse workspace
>   and preserve all your settings, simply copy the
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings directory into
>   your new workspace directory.

But..

> Do not copy other directories! There are project specific settings and
>   since your old projects are left in your old workspace, the copied
>   settings would not be valid and you would get some nasty exceptions at
>   eclipse startup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is synchronise workspace folder via Dropbox or UbuntuOne

Comment: Eclipse doesn't like Dropbox, you'll get a lot of error because the Android SDK folder is not at the same path on both computers